# Spring authentication for calls after login?

Tags: java, spring-security

In my project i am authenticating the project with spring security. Brief code snippet from SpringConfig.xml is below

```
<bean id="UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/userLogin" />
    </bean>
```

It works fine and i understands how spring security internally handles that.

But i am not getting which interceptor(or some other mechanism )
in spring security checks whether authenticated user exists in session for successive. Say if user logs in successfully, now he want to create
some action(like creating department), for this spring security needs to check whether user logged in or not. *where it is happening?*

If we dont use third party authentication library like spring security, Most of the web apps  generally authenticates the user while log in
and put the user info under session(*i can see this happening in spring security with above configuration*). 
Then for any succesive action, apps verifies if authenticated user exists under session or not. If yesaction is allowed otherwise
 he is redirected to login screen. **But i am not sure where it is happening ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key component in Spring Security is its [*security filter chain*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). With configuration you define what sort of filters are participating in the chain. These are some default ones (check the official documentation and JavaDoc for more information):

- `ChannelProcessingFilter` - does the request need to be HTTPS?
- **`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` - do we have already authenticated user stored on HTTP session?**
- `ConcurrentSessionFilter` - is user authenticated more than once / twice / ...,
- authentication processing filters

  - `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` - is the request `POST /login`? Should we call `AuthenticationManager`?
  - ...
- `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` - do you want to integrate with Servlet API security?
- `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` - do you want to remember authentication in a cookie?
- `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` - do you want to have a special *anonymous* authentication for unauthenticated requests?
- `ExceptionTranslationFilter` - is the thrown exception connected to access control? Should we initiate authentication (*entry point*)?
- `FilterSecurityInterceptor` - does the requested URI require authenticated user or a specific role? Should we throw `AccessDeniedException`?

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Actually my project has configured all filters you mentioned above.But My question is this. Say user has logged
in to application. Now for most of the application  urls except some specific features
i just want to check whether authenticated user exists or not in session which spring (i do not want to check any roles for them). 
I am not sure what configuration is needed to check whether authenticated user exist in session without any authorization/role check?

Comment: If you are using expression based checking, you can use `isAuthenticated()` as your access condition. If you are using the old security attribute checking, then there is a keyword `IS_AUTHENTICATED`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html